# React.js Dropdown component doesn't hide on button click

Tags: reactjs

I'm facing a problem in the making of clickable `Dropdown` component. My task is to show a menu when a button is clicked and hide the menu when the user clicks anywhere in the document or whether a click on the same button, also all components should be functional components.

I'm using 3rd party package named `classnames` which help to conditionally join `CSS` classes, also using a `React ContextAPI` to pass props to `Dropdown` child components.

`Dropdown` component depends upon 2 child components.

DropdownToggle -
(Renders a clickable button)

DropdownMenu -
(Renders a div with menu items)

**Problem:**

Whenever I open a menu and click anywhere in the document menu works perfectly, but when I open a menu and want to hide with a button click it didn't work. I think the problem is inside the `useEffect` hook of the `Dropdown` component.

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/dry-fire-iv57h)

**Demo:**

[image: Dropdown]

Here is the main `App` component which renders all components.

**App.js**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Dropdown from "./Dropdown";
import DropdownToggle from "./DropdownToggle";
import DropdownMenu from "./DropdownMenu";
import "./dropdown.css";

// App component
class App extends Component {
  state = {
    isOpen: false
  };

  toggle = () => {
    alert("Button is clicked");
    this.setState({
      isOpen: !this.state.isOpen
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="app">
        <Dropdown isOpen={this.state.isOpen} toggle={this.toggle}>
          <DropdownToggle>Dropdown</DropdownToggle>
          <DropdownMenu>
            <div>Item 1</div>
            <div>Item 2</div>
          </DropdownMenu>
        </Dropdown>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Main **src** code:

**DropdownContext.js**

```
import {createContext} from 'react';
// It is used on child components.
export const DropdownContext = createContext({});
// Wrap Dropdown with this Provider.
export const DropdownProvider = DropdownContext.Provider;
```

**Dropdown.js**

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import classNames from "classnames";
import { DropdownProvider } from "./DropdownContext";


/**
 * Returns a new object with the key/value pairs from `obj` that are not in the array `omitKeys`.
 * @param obj
 * @param omitKeys
 */
const omit = (obj, omitKeys) => {
  const result = {};
  // Get object properties as an array
  const propsArray = Object.keys(obj);
  propsArray.forEach(key => {
    // Searches the array for the specified item, if the item is not found it returns -1 then
    // construct a new object and return it.
    if (omitKeys.indexOf(key) === -1) {
      result[key] = obj[key];
    }
  });
  return result;
};

// Dropdown component
const Dropdown = props => {
  // Populate context value based on the props
  const getContextValue = () => {
    return {
      toggle: props.toggle,
      isOpen: props.isOpen
    };
  };

  // toggle function
  const toggle = e => {
    // Execute toggle function which is came from the parent component
    return props.toggle(e);
  };

  // handle click for the document object
  const handleDocumentClick = e => {
    // Execute toggle function of the parent
    toggle(e);
  };

  // Remove event listeners
  const removeEvents = () => {
    ["click", "touchstart"].forEach(event =>
      document.removeEventListener(event, handleDocumentClick, true)
    );
  };

  // Add event listeners
  const addEvents = () => {
    ["click", "touchstart"].forEach(event =>
      document.addEventListener(event, handleDocumentClick, true)
    );
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const handleProps = () => {
      if (props.isOpen) {
        addEvents();
      } else {
        removeEvents();
      }
    };
    // mount
    handleProps();
    // unmount
    return () => {
      removeEvents();
    };
  }, [props.isOpen]);

  // Condense all other attributes except toggle `prop`.
  const { className, isOpen, ...attrs } = omit(props, ["toggle"]);
  // Conditionally join all classes
  const classes = classNames(className, "dropdown", { show: isOpen });

  return (
    <DropdownProvider value={getContextValue()}>
      <div className={classes} {...attrs} />
    </DropdownProvider>
  );
};

export default Dropdown;
```

`Dropdown` component has a parent i.e. a `Provider` whenever `Provider` values will change child components will access those values.
Secondly, on the DOM it will render a `div` which consists of `Dropdown` markup structure.

**DropdownToggle.js**

```
import React, {useContext} from 'react';
import classNames from 'classnames';
import {DropdownContext} from './DropdownContext';

// DropdownToggle component
const DropdownToggle = (props) => {

    const {toggle} = useContext(DropdownContext);

    const onClick = (e) => {
        // If props onClick is not undefined
        if (props.onClick) {
            // execute the function
            props.onClick(e);
        }
        toggle(e);
    };

    const {className, ...attrs} = props;

    const classes = classNames(className);


    return (
        // All children would be render inside this. e.g. `svg` & `text`
        <button type="button" className={classes} onClick={onClick} {...attrs}/>
    );
};

export default DropdownToggle;
```

**DropdownMenu.js**

```
import React, { useContext } from "react";
import classNames from "classnames";
import { DropdownContext } from "./DropdownContext";

// DropdownMenu component
const DropdownMenu = props => {
  const { isOpen } = useContext(DropdownContext);

  const { className, ...attrs } = props;
  // add show class if isOpen is true
  const classes = classNames(className, "dropdown-menu", { show: isOpen });

  return (
    // All children would be render inside this `div`
    <div className={classes} {...attrs} />
  );
};

export default DropdownMenu;
```

Comment: If you print out the `isOpen` state in `toggle()`, you can see it gets fired once when the menu opens, but then gets fired twice when trying to close. This double firing is what makes it stay open. Haven't debugged the cause of the double `toggle` firing but yeah

Comment: @Jayce444 Yes, I think you're saying correctly. Whenever `props.isOpen` state value is changed the `useEffect` hook trigger a `handleProp()` function.

Comment: Posted a fix, though be careful about document event listeners in general

Answer (score 3):

`Jayce444` answer is correct. When you click the button, it fires once, then the event bubbles up to the document and fires again.

I just want to add another alternative solution for you. You can use `useRef` hook to create a reference of `Dropdown` node and check if the current event target is `button` element or not. Add this code to your `Dropdown.js` file.

```
import React, { useRef } from "react";

const Dropdown = props => {
  const containerRef = useRef(null);

  // get reference of the current div
  const getReferenceDomNode = () => {
    return containerRef.current;
  };

  // handle click for the document object
  const handleDocumentClick = e => {
    const container = getReferenceDomNode();
    if (container.contains(e.target) && container !== e.target) {
      return;
    }
    toggle(e);
  };

  //....

  return (
    <DropdownProvider value={getContextValue()}>
      <div className={classes} {...attrs} ref={containerRef} />
    </DropdownProvider>
  );
};
export default Dropdown;
```

Answer (score 0):

The toggling function is linked to both the document, and the button itself. So when you click the button, it fires once, then the event bubbles up to the `document` and fires again. Gotta be careful attaching event listeners to the entire `document` object. Add a line to stop the event propagation in your `Dropdown.js` file:

```
// toggle function
const toggle = e => {
 // Execute toggle function which is came from the parent component
 e.stopPropagation(); // this stops it bubbling up to the document and firing again
 return props.toggle(e);
};
```